# Configuring SSL Restlet server with Spring IoC?

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, inversion-of-control

So, google is being unhelpful today.

There's [this page](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/https), but that shows you how to set up an SSL restlet in *code*.

How do you do it in Spring XML?

Here's what I have now:

```
<bean id="container" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
            <property name="server">
                    <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServer">
                            <constructor-arg value="http" />
                            <constructor-arg value="3080" />
                    </bean> 
            </property>     
            <property name="defaultTarget" ref="router"/>
    </bean>
```

I could just use the constructor args "https" and "3443", but how do you set the keystore location for the server key and the password and type and yadda yadda yadda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this example?

Java:

```
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class RestletApplication extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public String present() {
        return "hello, world";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("restlet-context.xml").registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

Spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="top" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="server">
            <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServer">
                <constructor-arg value="https"/>
                <constructor-arg value="8183"/>
                <property name="parameters">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="sslContextFactory">org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory</prop>
                        <prop key="keyStorePath">/my/path/to/serverX.jks</prop>
                        <prop key="keyStorePassword">password</prop>
                        <prop key="keyPassword">password</prop>
                        <prop key="keyStoreType">JKS</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTarget">
            <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
                <property name="attachments">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="/v1" value="RestletApplication"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Seems to work with Restlets 2.3.4.

Based on:

- [The sample page you provided](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/https)
- Source code of SpringServer from [Restlet.org's Maven Repo](http://maven.restlet.org)
- [Restlet.org's (in)complete Spring Example](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/spring/example)
- [The first Restlet web service: "Hello world!"](http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/SIMBAD/courses/doku.php?id=teaching_assistant:web_services:restful_helloworld)

Comment: THAT'S the magic (the "properties" property with properties inside). This also works on 2.1.7 (except it's org.restlet.ext.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory), which in my case was the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and I've managed to solve it the following way.

In my property file I have the following:

```
trustStore.path = /path/to/certificate/cert.jks
trustStore.password = CertPassword
```

And in the xml-configuration:

```
<bean id="trustStore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">${trustStore.path}</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword">${trustStore.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Meh. If I have to do this with System Properties, I'd just as soon use -D on the JVM command line from my startup script. Surely there's got to be a Spring XML idiom to do what's in the sample code linked in the question.

Comment: In my case I could not use as JVM instruction directly. BTW there is a description for this: [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html)